# How to use translator websites?

Tags: translation, software

When I recently checked out the Google Translate website, where I translated some text from English into Tamil, I found that it translates individual words literally but does not translate sentences as a whole. Therefore sentence translations into Tamil end up incorrect. So how does one use this translation tool, or are there any other translator websites available which can translate entire sentences, and not merely perform word-by-word translations? If so, I'd welcome your suggestions.

[image: Google translate]

Comment: The best translator is someone who understands both languages. A computer only barely "understands" any language - so translating between two languages it barely understands, is understandably a very hard problem.

Comment: so for new learners how this can be overcome?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English Language and Usage, but rather about how to best use this or that piece of software.

Comment: @Emmanuel, I think the only real course of action is to either learn both the languages, or find someone who already has.

Comment: so is there any other translator websites which has more powerful than google translator?

Comment: Translation software as a whole is not powerful enough to do correct translations all the time. Also, this is off-topic for this site.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using a website, not the English language.

Comment: Questions about using web applications belong on our sister site [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). However, just as others I strongly recommend you do not use translator websites. *Especially* if you are a beginner. You yourself have just provided all the proof you needed that *they do not work.* Forget they even exist. Never mind complete sentences: Google Translate can't even get individual words right. Like, sometimes it can't even tell Thursday from Friday. No, really. And that's one of the very *best* tools out there. But it is still utter rubbish. Do not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google translate is, as far as my experience goes, one of the better, if not one of the best (free) options you have. But indeed it is flawed. For some standard sentences, it is able to provide correct translations.
I would in your example, for instance, simply use "How are you" to get a translation. In general, certainly between languages that are not even of the same language family, do not expect *any* software any time soon to be able to do good full text translations.